# SSLHandshake in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, handshake

I sent Upgrade Header in httpwebrequest header on port 80 to use TLS.Server responded successfully with 101 switching protocol response and hence upgrading the protocol.
      Now I want to know how to start SSL handshake on the same port in C#.?

Comment: Using `Upgrade` (as defined in [RFC 2817](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817)) isn't HTTPS and is extremely rare (perhaps used by Cups). Is it really what you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be intervening in the headers (by adding "Upgrade"). Let HttpWebRequest do it's thing.

Have you tried using this which specifically tells it to use SSL, but over port 80:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://your.host.com:80/test.htm");
```